# Was all the source material from the Zetsuen no Tempest manga adapted into the anime?

Tags: zetsuen-no-tempest

Was all the source material from the Zetsuen no Tempest manga adapted into the anime? I could check myself but I'd rather avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Baka-Updates](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=45115):

```
Starts at Volume 1, Chapter 1
Ends at Chapter 44 with some differences
```

Manga has 50 chapters **and** additional materials (Guidebook)